# jQuery to take value from input and check if it's right. If so, it should post how many are correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to take the value of an input and check if the answer is right I don't want it to just say that it's correct, I want it to look through and post how many are correct with numbers, and how many are incorrect. I had problems with posting the code below so here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BBaughn/4rww1mhy/

This one has the better jQuery in it. This one has the worse one: http://jsfiddle.net/BBaughn/cqsah8aw/

(and because it tells me I can't post because jsfiddle.net needs to be accompanied by code, here is 2 questions of my HTML)

```
  <p>Who is the best programmer that you know? (type only the first name)</p>
  <input type="textbox" id="best-programmer" placeholder="(e.g. Jonathan)"><br><br>
  <!--Answer: BRENDON-->

  <p>What element starts with the letter "K"</p>
  <input type="textbox" id="element" placeholder="(Hint: periodic table)">
  <br>
  <br>
  <!--Answer: POTASSIUM-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var answers = [progam = 'BRENDON',
element = 'KRYPTON',
planet = 'PLUTO',
island = "GREENLAND",
prague = "CZECH REPUBLIC"
];

var total = 0;
for (var i=0; i < answers.length; i++) {
total += answers[i];
var post = '<div class="posting-score">Score: '+ answers[i] +'</div>';
$(post).appendTo('.scores');
}
```

to

```
  var answers = [program, 'BRENDON',
                 element, 'KRYPTON',
                 planet, 'PLUTO',
                 island, "GREENLAND",
                 prague, "CZECH REPUBLIC"
                ];

  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < answers.length-1; i+=2) {
      total += (answers[i] == answers[i+1]);
  }

  var post = '<div class="posting-score">Score: '+ total +'</div>';
  $(post).appendTo('.scores');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Drakes/cqsah8aw/1/

Comment: where do I put this in my jQuery?

Comment: Please look at my fiddle

Answer (score -1):

You have to set a  section in your html code and use the syntax: $(#"id of element").val(); thats how you get the value of an input or any other element.

Comment: check the first JSFiddle link. I already do that. I want it to post the numbers of how many are correct, not it repeatedly saying "Score: correct" or "Score: incorrect"

Comment: Could you add an example visually off how you want it to be displayed, that way am able to understand  your question better.

Comment: You are reading through 6 questions. You then type the answer to the questions. To check if you are right, you click the button to give you the score. It says "Score: 5 correct! 1 incorrect!"